# Error, Null Pointer Exception for SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

So I keep getting the same error no matter how many times I try to tweak my code here and there. I will be posting every little bit of code that has to do with the error.

**I will not include unnecessary code so if my code doesn't look complete it's because I cut it out to make it easier for people to diagnose the issue!**

**First Class**

I wrote !!! error !!! after the code that was said to have been the cause of the error according to my log.

```
SharedPreferences sf;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
sf = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
checkCookie();
}

//function for making sure there's data 
public void checkCookie() {
        editor = sf.edit();
        if (sf.getInt("cookies", -1) == -1) {
            editor.putInt("cookies", 0);
        }
    }
//function for retrieving amount of cookies
public int getCookies()
    {
        editor = sf.edit(); !!! Error here !!!
        int x = sf.getInt("cookies", 0);
        return x;
    }
//function for changing amount of cookies
public void changeCookies(int x)
    {
        editor = sf.edit();
        editor.putInt("cookies", x);
    }
```

**Second Class**

I put !!! error !!! at the second error given which basically is what calls the function with the error in it.

```
//MyActivity is the first class
MyActivity mCookie = new MyActivity();

//function for adding cookies
public void cookieCalc(){
        if (Math.abs((5-(millis/1000))) <= 0.005)
            mCookie.changeCookies(100 * CB); ... much more similar code

//an if statement within a function which just calls the function getcookies and cookiecalc
if (loop == 2){
cookieCalc();
myText.setText("= " + mCookie.getCookies()); !!! this calls the function which gives error !!!
}
```

The error is 100% because of SharedPreferences as it worked with normal variables, but I needed to save the variables and was told this is a very easy method to do so. If all of this is still not enough and I cannot explain it to you I will then paste my entire code on gitHub or another viewing platform.

**Error Logs**

```
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.z0nen.slidemenu.MyActivity.changeCookies(MyActivity.java:74)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.z0nen.slidemenu.menu1_Fragment.cookieCalc(menu1_Fragment.java:75)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.z0nen.slidemenu.menu1_Fragment$1.onClick(menu1_Fragment.java:148)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10571)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
04-27 21:11:46.258 26975-26975/app.z0nen.menu E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: The `Activity` class is not meant to be the base class for everything, and you cannot instantiate an `Activity` subclass with `new` and have it work correctly. For one thing, `onCreate()` will not be called, which seems to be the cause of your current NPE.

Comment: onCreate is on the main function it what creates my app. I tried to do system.out.println but I couldn't find it anywhere within my code. I don't have an activity subclass I just made a blank constructor and had it so it can just receive information from it.

Comment: You should pass a Context to your second class, not create an non-managed Activity

Comment: the MyActivity mCookie = new MyActivity(); was created on my fragment.java. I don't believe this caused my crashing at all. It was only when I added the preferences after. I only did this purely so I can talk from 1 class to another because that is the only method I know how.

Answer (score 1):

You should never create activity instance by yourself! Only system should do that.

If you create instance yourself, onCreate will never get called, as this instance won't go through standard activity lifecycle.

Comment: I am a little confused by this. because I have no syntax error and it seems like it can properly communicate with my activity class.

Comment: Is there a way I can check if it runs my onCreate?

Comment: Use logging. But nothing calls onCreate if you create instance of activity yourself. Its just plain java then

Comment: Ok, so I moved everything and I mean everything over to my fragment class and removed MyActivity mCookie = new MyActivity();. I am still getting the same null pointer exception error. I added Context to my sharedPreferences as well but It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok, officially fixed the null error. It was caused because inside a fragment where it's onCreateView I had to write - SharedPreferences sf = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0):

do not new instance by yourself.  onCreate was br

Comment: onCreate was been override

Comment: Hi MurphyBin. You can update your answer by clicking on the "[edit]" link under the post. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Solved

SharedPreferences sf = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

because it was in a fragment class I had to add this.getActivity() and I also ended up adding Activity.MODE_PRIVATE. I probably was getting null pointer exception because it had no way to access my Activity class because fragments extend something else? Just a guess of mine, so far it is still not working how I want it to but I prevented crashes. *edit* it wasn't working because I didn't do editor.commit(); to save the changes.

Comment: This is not the proper solution. As pointed out by _everyone else here_, you should not be instantiating the activity yourself.

Comment: the error I was getting was a null pointer exception. The activity was a dumb thing I did, but it was not causing the error. Please don't just say that my solution is false when it made my code finally work. I spent at least 20 hours trying to fix this, I am in no shape or form good at coding this was not just me being lazy.